# SQL Server 2005 Create Table with Column Default value range

Tags: sql-server-2005, default-value, ddl

Trying to finish up some homework and ran into a issue for creating tables. How do you declare a column default for a range of numbers. Its reads: "Column Building (default to 1 but can be 1-10)"  I can't seem to find ...or know where to look for this information.

```
CREATE TABLE tblDepartment
(
Department_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
Department_Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Division_Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
City varchar(255) default 'spokane' NOT NULL,
Building int default 1 NOT NULL,
Phone varchar(255)
)
```

I tried Building int default 1 Between 1 AND 10 NOT NULL, that didn't work out
I tried Building int default 1-10, the table was created but I don't think its correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add [CHECK Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) to the column.

```
ALTER TABLE tblDepartment
ADD CONSTRAINT chkbuilding CHECK (Building >=1 AND Building <= 10 );
```

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed alter table, just create. Here's what I came up with from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp:

    CREATE TABLE tblDepartment
    (
    Building int default 1 NOT NULL,
    Check (Building >=1 AND Building <= 10 )
    )